# VBA won't translate vba reference into excel reference

Tags: vba, excel

Good morning all,

I have a problem with vba translating formulas into excel:

I've got this code:

```
'Tramos para calcular el total, mañana, tarde y noche
TramoIni = Array(4, 20, 36, 4)
TramoFin = Array(51, 35, 51, 19)

'Formulas
FormulaTramo = _
    Array("=SUMIFS('Mapa Turnos'!C[4],'Mapa Turnos'!C1,RC1,'Mapa Turnos'!C3,RC2)/30", _
        "=R[-1]C*(1-SUM(R[5]C:R[8]C))", _
    "=IFERROR(IF(IFERROR((R[13]C*R[-1]C*1800)/R[3]C,0)/R[2]C>1,1," _
        & "IFERROR((R[13]C*R[-1]C*1800)/R[3]C,0)/R[2]C),0)", _
    "=sla(IF(R[-2]C=0,0,IF(R[-2]C<1,1,R[-2]C)),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(RC2,Objetivos!C2,0),4," _
        & ",,""Objetivos"")),R[1]C,R[2]C)", _
    "=IF(AND(R[-7]C>0,R[-11]C=0),""SI"",""NO"")", _
    "=1", _
    "=1", _
    "=SUM(RC1:RC2)", _
    "=R[-11]C-R[-2]C", _
    "=CallCapacity(R[-12]C,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(RC2,Objetivos!C2,0),3," _
        & ",,""Objetivos"")),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(RC2,Objetivos!C2,0),4,,,""Objetivos"")),R[-8]C)", _
    "=IF(R[-1]C>R[-10]C,R[-10]C,R[-1]C)", "=Utilisation(R[-14]C,R[-11]C,R[-10]C)")

LastRow = ws.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row
Col = ws.Range("XDF4").End(xlToLeft).Column
ColTotal = ws.Cells.Find("Total").Column
ColF = ColTotal - 1
ColMañana = ws.Cells.Find("Mañana").Column
ColTarde = ws.Cells.Find("Tarde").Column
ColNoche = ws.Cells.Find("Noche").Column
For i = 1 To UBound(KPI)
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(4, 1), ws.Cells(LastRow, Col)).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=KPI(i)
    If KPI(i) <> "5.Pronóstico" And KPI(i) <> "92.Requeridos" Then
        With ws.Range(ws.Cells(5, 4), ws.Cells(LastRow, ColF)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "'" & FormulaTramo(i - 1)
        End With
    End If
    For x = 0 To UBound(TramoIni)
        'Formulas total, mañana, tarde y noche
        FormulaTotal = _
            Array("=SUM(RC" & TramoIni(x) & ":RC" & TramoFin(x) & ")/2", _
                "=SUM(RC" & TramoIni(x) & ":RC" & TramoFin(x) & ")/2", _
                "=IFERROR(IF(SUMPRODUCT(RC" & TramoIni(x) & ":RC" & TramoFin(x) & ",R[2]C" & TramoIni(x) & _
                    ":R[2]C" & TramoFin(x) & ")/R[2]C>1,1,SUMPRODUCT(RC" & TramoIni(x) & _
                    ":RC" & TramoFin(x) & ",R[2]C" & TramoIni(x) & ":R[2]C" & TramoFin(x) & ")/R[2]C),0)", _
                "=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(RC" & TramoIni(x) & ":RC" & TramoFin(x) & ",R[1]C" & TramoIni(x) & _
                    ":R[1]C" & TramoFin(x) & ")/R[1]C,0)", _
                "=SUM(RC" & TramoIni(x) & ":RC" & TramoFin(x) & ")", _
                "=SUM(RC" & TramoIni(x) & ":RC" & TramoFin(x) & ")/2", _
                "=IF(COUNTIF(RC" & TramoIni(x) & ":RC" & TramoFin(x) & ",""SI"")>0,""SI"",""NO"")", _
                "=IFERROR(SUM(RC" & TramoIni(x) & ":RC" & TramoFin(x) & ")/2,0)", _
                "=SUM(RC" & TramoIni(x) & ":RC" & TramoFin(x) & ")", _
                "=IF(R[-2]C>R[-10]C,R[-10]C,R[-2]C)", _
                "=IFERROR(IF(SUMPRODUCT(RC" & TramoIni(x) & ":RC" & TramoFin(x) & ",R[-14]C" & _
                    TramoIni(x) & ":R[-14]C" & TramoFin(x) & ")/R[-14]C>1,1,SUMPRODUCT(RC" & _
                    TramoIni(x) & ":RC" & TramoFin(x) & ",R[-14]C" & TramoIni(x) & ":R[-14]C" & _
                    TramoFin(x) & ")/R[-14]C),0)")
        With ws.Range(ws.Cells(5, TramoFin(0) + x + 1), ws.Cells(LastRow, TramoFin(0) + x + 1)). _
            SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                .FormulaR1C1 = "'" & FormulaTotal(i - 1)
        End With
    Next x
Next i
ws.Rows(4).AutoFilter
x = ws.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row
i = ws.Range("XDF4").End(xlToLeft).Column
ws.Range(ws.Cells(5, 4), ws.Cells(x, i)).Value = ws.Range(ws.Cells(5, 4), ws.Cells(x, i)).Value
```

This is just some arrays containing formulas and the column where they should start taking values.

The thing is that the if, countif and sum aren't taking the cells references when going to excel:

[image: Before Converting]

As you can see above every formula has the same cell reference, the one that vba has.

But later on when we convert it to excel (last line of code):

[image: After converting]

As you can see sumproducts worked well, but the rest are taking literally the column RC and the row which was supposed to be the column reference on VBA.

Any thoughts what could be doing this? I need to work like this because this worksheet can have up to 7k rows and 50+ columns with formulas in like the 80% of them so introducing the formulas in every loop would take ages, instead I'm doing this so they all recalculate at the same time.

This way still takes ages to calculate and I don't know if there is a more efficient way to input so many formulas which include erlangs and custom functions.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This is some very scary code. Difficult if not impossible to follow.  Please see how to create a **[mcve]** and try to cut down the code so as to only include the section that's causing the problem.

Comment: Hello @ashleedawg this is the minimum part to understand the problem... It has 2 arrays full of formulas, I believe those are needed in case I'm missing something is wrong.  2 Arrays with the columns used on 1 loop. Then some variables to understand where it all does and the 2 loops filling the formulas... I don't believe  I can paste a code with lesser information.

Comment: Hi @Srijan when working with VBA references: R[2]C means 2 rows down from where you are on the same column, R2C means row 2  and the column you are in. the "[]" are for offsets, I need to get RC20:RC35 meaning this row, column 20 to this row column 35 if is used the [] it would mean this row 20 columns from here, this row 35 columns from here.

Comment: Note that the term is *relative cell references*, not "VBA references".  (A1 cell notation works perfectly fine in VBA as well.)

Comment: If the problem is that the cell notation styles are getting confused, then you should ***switch to either `R1C1` or `A1` notation for everything**; both worksheet and code instead of going back and forth.  They don't work well together. You can use R1C1 solely by enabling the checkbox within the settings in `File>Options>Formulas>"R1C1 Reference Style"`

Comment: but I don't see that the problem is like that... My macro fills up some arrays with formulas, then paste the formulas in a loop. Because it takes too long to calculate everytime the macro inserts formulas, the macro writes a ' before the formula so it goes as text and not formula. Finally, when are the formulas are pasted the .value = .value kills the ' and everything turns into formula. As you can see all formulas go in A1 notation, but only sumproduct and if are taking them correctly, the rest are not...

Comment: Why not switch them all to A1 (and use `OFFSET` if you need relative references)?

Comment: Try changing `.Value` in last line on the left side to `.FormulaR1C1`. _Because it takes too long to calculate everytime the macro inserts formulas, the macro writes a ' before the formula so it goes as text and not formula_ - much better way to handle it is to disable automatic calculations.

Comment: Have to agree with @ashleedawg - scary looking code to read through and look for problems.  I didn't try to test it as I can see you haven't defined the variables or added the procedure heading so I can't just paste it into Excel and test (and then go "ah yes, I see what he means").  _One thing though:_  You should test to see if your `FIND` actually finds anything and also define the other arguments in FIND - it remembers the last settings you used, so could be searching in the comments or be case sensitive....

Comment: Hi guys! So @BrakNicku nailed it! now all the formulas get the reference the should in excel! Could you make your comment an answer so I can mark it as the answer? As for darren, the code is big just because of the  arrays which contain the formulas... there is no way I could shorten it without taking info. The finds are ok, they just look for a column number and they can't miss. All variables are declared but there is a bit of code before and As you said it already looks scary with this size, didn't want to make it larger. Thank you for your comments guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MCVE of the problem in question:

```
Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "'" & "=SUM(RC20:RC25)"
Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value
```

Formula in RC-notation is assigned to the `Value` property. Excel tries to recognize the formula type. There are only absolute references in this formula, so it looks like valid A1-notation relative formula.

Some of the formulas containing relative references (with square brackets) were correctly recognized as RC notation - because those would not be valid A1 formulas.

To solve the problem, array with formulas needs to be assigned to `FormulaR1C1` property:

`ws.Range(ws.Cells(5, 4), ws.Cells(x, i)).FormulaR1C1 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(5, 4), ws.Cells(x, i)).Value`

Much better way to avoid long calculations during code execution is to disable automatic calculation:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'all code here
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked out fine.
PS: before all my macros run this macro goes first:
Sub AhorroMemoria()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End Sub
still this one goes wayy so slow, I imagine because the insane number of calculations excel has to do.